# Add and delete thumbnail using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I need to create and delete thumbnail image in my yii2 app. I must to have max 5 images and when I was choose files I may to see thumbnails of that images.
I added images in my view with that:

```
?= $form->field($images, 'imagesFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*','id'=>'gallery-photo-add'])->label(false) ?>
```

and I can get images in my controller:

```
 $images->imagesFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($images,'imagesFiles');
```

How can I see thumbnails? I need to create ajax request? If yes, how I can delete different images? Or add them to my view maybe with some id's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see images after choosing them from disk, before submit form, you can preview selected files in view using javascript, eg:

```
$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    var input = $(this)[0];
    var images = $('#some-div');
    for (var i=0; i<input.files.length; i++) {
        if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                images.append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" />');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
});
```